# Debuggar com fwrite() em PHP

Tags: php, debug

Fala galera, me surgiu a necessidade de consumir uma API com um volume de dados muito grande, e preciso fazer isso a partir de uma linguagem pois a API possui limitações, e vou de PHP.

O problema é que eu preciso fazer diversas requisições e algumas delas acabam dando erro 429. Quando esse erro acontece, eu queria ver ele de alguma forma sem ter que esperar o script parar de rodar, pq as vezes fica mais de 10 minutos rodando e seria interessante saber oq ta acontecendo.

Para saber qual foi o dado perdido eu cheguei a solução de tentar debuggar de forma meio porca:

```
$i = 0;
$log_file = fopen('arquivo-log', 'w');

while($i < 5) {
   $req = curl_get('url-qualquer'); // função que eu utilizo, mas nao vem ao caso

   $body = "HTTP Status: {$req['http_code']}, Request Time: $i \n-------------------\n";
   fwrite($log_file, $body);

   sleep(2); // para o script nao rodar muito rapido e eu poder visualizar a interação
   $i++;
}

fclose($log_file);
```

Porém o arquivo é escrito de forma completa quando o script termina de ser executado. O que eu queria é ver ele sendo escrito a cada vez que entrasse no laço. Consegui isso fazendo um insert num banco de dados, daí eu vejo os dados sendo inseridos ao longo da execução, mas não acredito que seja a melhor solução.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou fazendo algo errado ou é impossível fazer isso visto q o php é interpretado e daí compilado por completo antes de algum output?

Ou existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso, talvez com um Xdebug e tals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tentaria substituir fwrite por [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php), que é basicamente o mesmo que um fopen, fwrite e fclose a cada execução.

```
$i = 0;
$log_file = 'arquivo-log';

while($i < 5) {
   $req = curl_get('url-qualquer'); // função que eu utilizo, mas nao vem ao caso

   $body = "HTTP Status: {$req['http_code']}, Request Time: $i \n-------------------\n";
   file_put_contents($log_file, file_get_contents($log_file) . $body);

   sleep(2); // para o script nao rodar muito rapido e eu poder visualizar a interação
   $i++;
}
```

Caso deseje que o conteúdo do arquivo seja escrito em ordem cronológica descendente (execução mais nova em cima) é só inverter o concatenamento entre $body e file_get_contents().

Essa "técnica", falando de performance, é um pouco mais lenta que abrir o arquivo uma única vez, mas para fins de DEBUG é mais que suficiente.

**EDIT 1:**

Ao invés de usar file_get_contents e concatenar com o conteúdo atual você pode passar a flag FILE_APPEND para o file_put_contents. Assim o PHP vai concatenar o conteúdo no fim do arquivo sem esvazia-lo antes.

`file_put_contents($log_file, $body, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, era isso mesmo q eu precisava, e como é um script pra um caso extremo, a performance pode ficar de lado, então a resposta foi perfeita :D.